# Ansible Set Dynamic Environment Variables

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, ansible

I know about Ansible's environment: command at the top of playbook, but I don't think that will work for me seeing how I don't know the variables value prior to the execution of the playbook.  I'm trying to retrieve package versions and PHP Modules and log them to a file.  I want to use regex to capture the version and store it to an environment variable.  Then I want to write that variable equals that variable's value to an environment file with a shell command.  I also want to pull an array from the environment and loop through that.  Ansible doesn't seem to persist the shell environment and the environment variable gets wiped out between commands.  This is simple in Bash.  Is this possible in Ansible?  I'm trying:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
      site_variables:
          code_directory: /home/
      dependency_versions:
          WGET_VERSION: placeholder
          PHP_MODULES: placeholder

  tasks: 
    - name: Retrieve Environment
      shell: export WGET_VERSION=$(wget --version | grep -o  'Wget [0-9]*.[0-9]*\+')
      shell: export PHP_MODULES=$(php -m)
      shell: echo "export {{ item }}={{ lookup('env',  item ) }}" >> {{ site_variables.code_directory }}/.env.log
      with_items:
        - WGET_VERSION


    - name: Write PHP Modules Out
      shell: export PHP_MODULES=$(php -m)
      shell: export PHP_MODULES=$(echo {{ lookup('env',  'PHP_MODULES') }} | sed 's/\[PHP Modules\]//g')
      shell: export PHP_MODULES=$(echo {{ lookup('env',  'PHP_MODULES') }} | sed 's/\[Zend Modules\]//g')
      shell: export PHP_MODULES=({{ lookup('env',  'PHP_MODULES') }}) 
      shell: echo "#  - {{ item.0 }}" >> {{ site_variables.code_directory }}/.env.log
      with_items:
        - "{{ lookup('env',  'PHP_MODULES') }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot going on here.

First, `lookup` always runs *on the ansible control host*, while the script that you pass to the `shell` module is running *on the remote server*.  So you will never be able to get a *remote* environment variable using `lookup`.

For details: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html

Secondly, environment variables don't propagate from a child to parent.  If you have a script that does this...

```
export MYVARIABLE=foo
```

...and you run that script, your current environment will not suddenly have a variable named `MYVARIABLE`.  This is just as true for processes spawned by Ansible as it is for processes spawned by your shell.

If you want to set an *ansible* variable, consider using the `register` keyword to get the value:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: get wget version
      command: wget --version
      register: wget_version_raw

    - name: extract wget version
      set_fact:
        wget_version: "{{ wget_version_raw.stdout_lines[0].split()[2] }}"

    - name: show wget version
      debug:
        msg: "wget version is: {{ wget_version }}"
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm following you entirely.  I ssh'ed into the remote host and set WGET_VERSION manually...so let's say WGET_VERSION=1.1.1.   {{ lookup('env',  item ) }} was actually pulling the environment variable from the remote_host that I set up manually (1.1.1) and logging it appropriately.  It just wasn't setting the new value through Ansible in shell: export WGET_VERSION=$(wget --version | grep -o  'Wget [0-9]*.[0-9]*\+').  I probably just need to think this over more as I definitely need to feed it all through an array in the end.  Maybe Ansible is just not the way to do this.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice!  I'm new to Ansible and it's definitely helpful.

Comment: Thanks again!  I got it working using set_fact, a set of parallel arrays, and escaped regex statements.  Seems like straight bash is more appropriate and cleaner in this case :P.